# Does the Skorokhod space with the uniform topology admit a smooth partition of unity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Does the Skorokhod Banach space $D[0,1]$ (cadlag functions equipped with the uniform norm) admit a smooth partition of unity? I found [Johanis - Smooth partitions of unity on Banach spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022123617301398), which provides several classes of Banach spaces with this property, but don't see how to relate the given criteria to the Skorokhod space.

Comment: The Skorohod space is not normed and thus not Banach.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Maybe it is a matter of notation: What I'm considering are the cadlag functions together with the topology given by the uniform norm. This is a non-separable Banach space (and as far as I know, non-separability was the main reason why Skorokhod introduced the four more common J and M topologies)

Comment: With the supremum norm topology the Skorohod space is linearly homeomorphic to $C([0,1])\oplus\ell^1([0,1])$ where neither or the factors has smooth bump functions by old results. Hence by reductio ad absurdum the answer is **no**, provided that the question is interpreted in the sense that every open cover has a subordinated smooth partition of unity..

Comment: @TaQ thanks for this point of view, apparently there is something I don't understand, as in the reference I quoted it is explicitly stated that $C([0,1])$ *does* admit a partition of unity. I will read some more and then comment further.

Comment: @TaQ I think that I understand now: A necessary condition for $C(K)$ to admit smooth partitions of unity is that $K$ be scattered (has no nonempty dense-in-itself subsets), which rules out intervals of the real line (so my previous comment was wrong). Would you mind extending your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it? In particular, could you provide some more details on the linear homeomorphism (the definition is clear, but continuity requires some work, doesn't it)?

Comment: My comment above was mistaken since $C([0,1])\oplus\ell^1([0,1])$ only continuously embeds in the Skorohod space $D$ as a proper nonclosed subspace. This in conjunction with the assumption of existence of smooth partitions of unity in $D$ *does not* (at least as I thought) lead to a contradiction with the results of Bonic and Frampton from 1965. See Section 14 (pp. 152−158, in particular 14.11(1)) in Kriegl and Michor's *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis* (AMS 1997) for an account of bump functions.

Comment: @TaQ Thanks for your answer and the reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Skorohod space $D$ has $C([0,1])$ as a Banach subspace that does not have smooth bump functions by results of Bonic and Frampton from 1965. If $D$ had smooth partitions of unity, it would posses smooth bump functions, hence also $C([0,1])$ which is false. So the answer is **no**.

See Section 14 (pp. 152−158, in particular 14.11(1)) in Kriegl and Michor's *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis* (AMS 1997) for an account on bump functions.